# Retaining previous form data

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I have a form that I could put on to one page, but for aesthetic reasons, I want to split into two. The original form, on submission, would go to a Servlet which would get the form data and insert it into a database. However, I don't know how to make this work when it is split into two different forms on two different pages. My forms are currently in html but I could change them to JSP if that is the solution. I do not want to use hidden fields; if there is no way to do it without hidden fields, then I will just put it on one page as my form has quite a few fields and hidden fields would mean basically doubling the amount of code. I also only want to use html or jsp for the forms; I don't want to use JavaBeans, and I want to avoid scripting in the jsp's. I have already done this by simply dividing the database logic into two and using the ID of the last inserted object as a hidden field, and the second form then uses that ID to update that item, but this is not an elegant solution and could cause a problem if one user submitted the first form and a different user submitted the second (the wrong item would be updated). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is one of the things the Session can be used for: store the data from the first page in the HttpSession and then in the second page retrieve the session data and save it to the database.

Comment: One question though: Does this mean cookies need to be enabled? It's not a problem anyway

Comment: Yep, in general sessions require cookies.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use javascript pagination (It'll save page loading time. Many online test applications adopt this approach)
   a) Either on submission on each part of form data will send to server using ajax call.(partial submission)
   b) Or the whole data will be maintained at client side only until whole form is completed and submitted successfully.
   (depends on your application need)
2. You can logically relate each part of form with some unique id & session id combination. In addition, if you are not willing/required to store whole form data in session, you can have primary key in session. It'll make database update process easier for 2nd or next part of form data.